# Swift : Error when swiping up

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, uigesturerecognizer

I kept on getting these errors when I try do a swipe up gesture.
Swiping "right" is alright but "up" would throw errors.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

> 2015-12-24 14:53:36.977 Swipes & Shake[58213:9895793] -[Swipes___Shake.ViewController swiped]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc549ea4400
>
> 2015-12-24 14:53:36.982 Swipes & Shake[58213:9895793] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swipes___Shake.ViewController swiped]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc549ea4400'
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> (lldb)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    
    var swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped")
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    }

func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    if let swipeGesture =  gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer
    {
        switch swipeGesture.direction
        {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            print("RIGHT")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
            print("UP")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `:` after `swiped` in `var swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped")`

Correct is `var swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped:")`

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not notice it at all