# iOS: Non-bouncing scroll for stack of stackviews with stationary element at the top

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder, uistackview

I am trying to use Xcode IB to create a scrollable group of 16 stackviews positioned one above the other with a 17th stationary stackview at the top that does not scroll. I want to be able to interact with the scrollable stackviews, so I don't want them to bounce back up immediately after I scroll down.

Any programming required I would do in Swift.

Currently I have:

- a vertical stackview at the top of the view (`Overview Stack View`) that contains

  - one horizontal stackview at the top of the Overview Stack View as the stationary element (this horizontal stackview contains 2 text fields)
  - a scrollview below that, which contains a UIView that in turn contains 16 horizontal stackviews positioned 50 units apart on the Y axis

I find that if I configure the scrollview with `Bounces` and `Bounces Vertically` in the Attributes Inspector, I can scroll the stackviews but they always bounce back up immediately, making them difficult or impossible to interact with. If I don't include `Bounces` and `Bounces Vertically`, the group of stackviews doesn't scroll at all.

Github repo [here](https://github.com/mhurwicz/testScrollStackviews)

This image shows the project in XCode:

[image: project in Xcode]

I have read a number of questions and answers on Stackoverflow (which is how I got this far) but none of the proposed solutions has helped me solve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for my situation:

1. Make ViewController a UIScrollView delegate.
2. Create an outlet to the Main ScrollView.
3. Add code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448662/swift-error-when-swiping-up). (I made some changes.)

See code for ViewController below (also in github).

Hope this helps someone!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainScroll: UIScrollView!

    let stackHeight: CGFloat = 30.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainScroll.delegate = self
        print("----- viewDidLoad -----")
        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swiped(_:)))
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swiped(_:)))
        swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    }

    func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if let swipeGesture =  gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer
        {
            switch swipeGesture.direction
            {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
                print("DOWN")
                if (mainScroll.contentOffset.y >= stackHeight) {
                    mainScroll.contentOffset.y = mainScroll.contentOffset.y - stackHeight
                }
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
                print("UP \(mainScroll.contentOffset.y)")
                if (mainScroll.contentOffset.y <= stackHeight*16 ) {
                    mainScroll.contentOffset.y = mainScroll.contentOffset.y+stackHeight
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```